# Can we call a single attribute entry (=one row) "a feature" of the Layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

For the single layer(for example Airport layer)  there are many entries in the attribute table.

Can we call single attribute row entry a feature of the Airport Layer?

Can somebody give clear view of layer and feature ?

Comment: yeah, you should explore the select by expression in the attribute table

Comment: Or you can simply click on it in the map window.

Comment: Can you include any code you have tried? Have you taken a look at [some examples](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer)?

Comment: You man want to read the [introduction to gis](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/index.html) on qgis.org. But in short: yes one row relates to one feature.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a layer is a set of features and each feature correspond to one row in the attribute table.

That being said one feature could be composed of several object (or collection) like in the case of multipoint, multiline or multipolygon. In that case each feature is composed of one or several part but all part are grouped in one feature and have one set of attribute (so one line in the table), you may think of a country composed of several island for exemple.